# Deleting a super classes variable

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have this class which I need to inherit.

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Coul you tell me how I could inherit this and remove the `username` variable from the super class?

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        required=True, label=_("Email")
    )

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #del super(LoginForm, self).username
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(
            request, *args, **kwargs
        )
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you realize that this (done naively, at least) would make instances `ofAuthenticationForm` lose the `username` part? Perhaps it should be the other way around, or you should factor the common parts out. Even if this is possible, it'd be rather confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is Django, you can just remove it from the `fields` dict:

```
class LoginForm(…):
    def __init__(…):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(…)
        self.fields.pop('username')
```

Comment: + 1 to this solution. I'd also add that this is probably the only good solution, because you actually cannot remove ``username`` from ``LoginForm`` because it is not in the ``LoginForm`` - static fields are not inherited, and thus you can only remove it from the base class. While removing it from the base class is cumbersome and error-prone, because other child classes may be affected by this.

Comment: Oops... Sorry, I meant to add the rest of the previous comment to the question, its not linked to this answer.